# console.clear() was prevented due to 'Preserve log'

Tags: console

I am new to the world of web development and I just finished Jonas Schmedtmann's JS course.

However, on the first project I wanted to work on, I encountered the following error and I cannot solve it.

After I ran the parcel and started writing a line of code for the javascript test, the first line of code written appears in the console, but then the problems appear.

After I write another code in the console, the following message persists: 'console.clear() was prevented due to 'Preserve log''', which has an indicator like a number before it.

The console freezes with this message, which only updates the numbers in front of it (numbers that increase from 2 to 2), when I add something to the console.

When I click on the error, it takes me to the source table, where it indicates that the error is in the following code:

// Handle HMR Update
let handled = assets.every(asset => {
return asset.type === 'css' || asset.type === 'js' && hmrAcceptCheck(module.bundle.root, asset.id, asset.depsByBundle);
});
if (handled) {
**console.clear();**

The error appears even if I checked the Preserve log function in the browser, but also if it is unchecked.

Thank you in advance!

I checked and unchecked the Preserver log option in the browser, but I still have the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're encountering an issue with Hot Module Replacement (HMR) in your project setup. The error you're seeing is related to the attempt to clear the console using `console.clear()`.

Here are a few suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Check Browser Console Settings:
   Ensure that you don't have any breakpoints or logs that may interfere with HMR. Sometimes, having breakpoints in your code can cause issues. Also, ensure that your browser console settings are not preventing the console from clearing.
2. Update Parcel:
   Ensure that you are using the latest version of Parcel. You can update Parcel by running the following command in your project directory:

   `npm install -g parcel-bundler`
3. Check Dependencies:
   Make sure all your project dependencies are up-to-date. You can do this by running:

   `npm update`
4. Check Your JavaScript Code:
   Review the JavaScript code you have written. Ensure there are no syntax errors or logical issues that might be causing unexpected behavior.
5. Disable Console Clear:
   If the issue persists, you can try commenting out or removing the `console.clear();` line from the HMR handling code in the Parcel source. This is a temporary workaround and may not be a recommended solution in the long term.
   Find the code block that looks like this:

   `if (handled) { console.clear(); }`

   And comment out or remove the `console.clear();` line:

   `if (handled) { // console.clear(); }`
6. Check for Browser Extensions:
   Sometimes, browser extensions can interfere with web development tools. Try disabling browser extensions one by one to see if any of them are causing the issue.
7. Browser Compatibility:
   Ensure that you are using a browser that is well-supported by Parcel for HMR. Popular choices include Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

After trying these steps, if the issue persists, you may want to look for specific information related to your Parcel version and the environment you are working in. Check the Parcel GitHub repository or community forums for any reported issues or updates.

Comment: It seems that I managed to solve the problem. Parcel version 2 was installed. Running the code you gave me, it runs version 1.12.5 of Parcel, which still seems to be an old one, but in which I no longer receive the error in the console. However, the terminal tells me that I have 56 of vulnerabilities, 44 moderate, 12 high and I don't know if this could be a problem in the future of the project.